# SQL request files with multiples tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tags, request

I'm currently designing a website for file hosting. I'm sorting files by tags and I have an issue for building a search request in SQL. If I search for multiple tags at once, i want to be able to get the files that have all these tags.

Below is an example of what i want to do. If my search is "#code #python", my request must return me the files that have both tags (file with id 2 in this example). If the search is just "#code", the request must return file 2 and 3.

Here is how i store all the data, i have a table for files, one for tags and an other one with the links between files and tags (files_tags).

```
Table Tags 
------------------------
| id | name            |
------------------------
|  1 | Code            |
------------------------
|  2 | Python          |
------------------------
|  3 | PHP             |
------------------------

Table Files
------------------------
| id | name            |
------------------------
| 1  | python.pdf      | ( #python )
------------------------
| 2  | main.py         | ( #code #python )
------------------------
| 3  | class.php       | ( #code #php )
------------------------

Table files_tags
------------------------
| id | tag | file      |
------------------------
| 1  |  1  | 2         |
------------------------
| 2  |  1  | 3         |
------------------------
| 3  |  2  | 1         |
------------------------
| 4  |  2  | 2         |
------------------------
| 5  |  3  | 3         |
------------------------
```

My current request is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT `files`.* FROM `files`, `files_tags`, `tags` WHERE `files`.`id` = `files_tags`.`file` AND `files_tags`.`tags` = `tags`.`id` AND `tags`.`name` LIKE %"#code #python"%;
```

But it gets me all the 3 files, not just file 2.

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, it works know.

```
select * from files where 2 = (select count(1) from tags inner join files_tags on files_tags.tag = tags.id where files_tags.file = files.id and tags.name in ("code","python"))
```

Comment: I think you need `where 2 <= ...` to get all files which have at least those 2 tags

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks odd. Try the following one instead:

```
SELECT `files`.`id`, `files`.`name`
FROM `files` 
      JOIN `files_tags` ON `files`.`id`=`files_tags`.`file`
      JOIN `tags` ON `files_tags`.`tag` = `tags`.`id` 
WHERE `tags`.`name` IN ('code','python');
GROUP BY `files`.`id`, `files`.`name`
```

Comment: the clause IN is an OR so i'm getting all the 3 files because each one match one the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like this:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM `files` f JOIN
     `files_tags` ft
     ON f.id = ft.file JOIN
    `tags` t
     ON ft.tags = t.id
WHERE FIND_IN_STR(t.name, @SearchStr)
GROUP BY f.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = LENGTH(@SearchStr) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@SearchStr, ',', '')) + 1;
```

This takes the liberty of changing the format of your search string.  Instead of "#", just use commas (with no spaces).  Of course, the above can be adapted to support "#", but the code requires more string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you sould take your search text, and use it as an array, that is , not a string. Split values by space " " so you have an array where each element represents a tag.

select * from files where 
length_of_tags_array = 
 (select count(1) from tags inner join files_tags on files_tags.tag = tags.id where files_tags.file = files.id and tags.name in ("+putyourtagshere+") 
)

- since your tags are strings, add each element enbetween quitations
- dont use like in this case for it would retrieve tags that are substring pof other tags such as "C" is a substring of "C#"
- remove the hashtag as well since it is not in your stored tag's name